# MySQL selecting random rows with one unique row within one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to select x random rows from a table, where one of the rows have to be a special row (thereby with a special field value) within one query?

Basically what I'm trying to create is a Guessing Game, where you have x amount of questions, with x amount of possible (checkbox selectable) answers!

This is how I select the answers currently... With 2 query's

```
$answers = 4; // This is the max amount of answers
```

// Just for testing the question_id is manually set

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `question_id` = 0 AND `correct` != 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " . ($answers - 1) . "";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `question_id` = 0 AND `correct` = 1 LIMIT 1";
```

The "question_id" tells which question we are talking about, and the "correct" just tells if that field is the correct answer

So is it possible to select x random rows from a table, where one of the rows have to be "the correct one", within one query?

Comment: Did you try using the UNION clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be use ***UNION*** ?

```
$answers = 4;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `question_id` = 0 AND `correct` != 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " . ($answers - 1) . "";

$query .= " UNION ";

$query .= "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `question_id` = 0 AND `correct` = 1 LIMIT 1";
```

With one single query, you will be able to get the desired result

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Damn, that gave me this error... Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: Ohh it needed to have parenthesis around each "query"

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE ... whatever ... AND `question_id` IN (5, 9, 12, 16, 2)
```

So, you first find the number of rows and then put the correct answer's ID in to the `WHERE IN` statement. Because you know the one you want, you can just surround it with random IDs from the table and then render them in a random fashion.

Comment: No, I don't know the answer's id, the only thing I know is the question_id and the amount of rows (answers) I want in return

Comment: Then generate random numbers inside the number of rows that exist

Comment: So you want me to make another query, to check for how many rows that exist, and then... well that didn't make it become only one query?